# How do I configure a grails domain class attribute to be stored in a table (postgrest 12.1)

Tags: grails

I have my domain class User with the attributes "nombre" and "apellido";

```
class Usuario {

  String nombre
  String  apellido

  static constraints = { nombre size: 5..15, blank: false
        apellido  size: 5..15, blank: false
      }

 static mapping = {
    table 'usuario'
    version false
    nombre column: 'First_Name'
    apellido column: 'First_Name'
    addresses lazy: false
}
  //   static mapping = {
 //       table 'Usuario'
 //   }*/
```

inside the controller I create two objects and save them to the linked database

```
class UsuarioController {

  def index() {
   def b = new Usuario(nombre: "matyui", apellido: "Rimollo")
   System.out.println(b.nombre)
  
   b.save(flush: true)
   def c = new Usuario(nombre: "marcio",apellido: "Razzor")
 
   c.save(flush: true)
 }
```

This creates a new table "usuario" for me, but it does not have these two attributes("nombre" and "apellido") but only an attribute "id" type bigint and attributre userpkey;
How can I get it to create the attributes of my domain class in the table of datasource? (I also tried to create a table and try to insert them but it didn't work(this action is commented in the code of the domain class "usuario")).See the picture in next link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOp8U.png

My version grails is 3.3.X  y my datasource is a postgreSQL;
Thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't apellido be Last_Name or Surname and not First_Name in your mapping block?

Comment: Yes, but the result is no different!!! even if I remove the mapping and the domain class remains like this :

       String nombre;
       String  apellido;

        static constraints = { nombre size: 5..15, blank: false
            apellido  size: 5..15, blank: false;
             }
 get  the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to **delete the Users table with capital letters;** It is seen that postgres took it as a single table, so as the legacy table did not have all the attributes that grails presses, it created another table with the missing attributes, but it did not update the legacy table since the code did not indicate it. See the final picture; thank every body.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shxra.png)